# Suppress use of Softmax in CrossEntropyLoss for PyTorch Neural Net

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, softmax, cross-entropy

I know theres no need to use a `nn.Softmax()` Function in the output layer for a neural net when using `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` as a loss function.

However I need to do so, is there a way to suppress the implemented use of softmax in `nn.CrossEntropyLoss` and instead use `nn.Softmax()` on my output layer of the neural network itself?

**Motivation**: I am using `shap` package to analyze the features influences afterwards, where I can only feed my trained model as an input. The outputs however don't make any sense then because I am looking at unbound values instead of probabilites.

**Example**: Instead of -69.36 as an output value for one class of my model, I want something between 0 and 1, summing up to 1 for all classes. As I can't alter it afterwards, the outputs need to be like this already during training.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of [nn.CrossEntropyLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) says,

> This criterion combines [nn.LogSoftmax()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=logsoftmax#torch.nn.LogSoftmax) and [nn.NLLLoss()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=nllloss#torch.nn.NLLLoss) in one single class.

I suggest you stick to the use of `CrossEntropyLoss` as the loss criterion. However, you can convert the output of your model into probability values by using the [softmax](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.functional.softmax) function.

**Please note**, you can always play with the output values of your model, you do not need to change the loss criterion for that.

But if you still want to use `Softmax()` in your network, then you can use the `NLLLoss()` as the loss criterion, only apply [log()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=log#torch.log) before feeding model's output to the criterion function. Similarly, if you use `LogSoftmax` instead in your network, you can apply [exp()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=exp#torch.exp) to get the probability values.

**Update**:

To use `log()` on the `Softmax` output, please do:

```
torch.log(prob_scores + 1e-20)
```

By adding a very small number (1e-20) to the `prob_scores`, we can avoid the `log(0)` issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i mixed up Softmax and Logsoftmax. Your last comment is actually an as obvious as genius idea, i think thats exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Edit: what i didnt think of: applying log results in a lot of nan values due to -inf from log(0)..

Comment: Yeah that solves the issue, probably was only happing due to a very rare rounding issue. That works as expected thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `nn.NLLLoss()`. 
`nn.CrossEntropyLoss` computes log softmax of the input scores and computes the negative log-likelihood loss. If you already have log probabilities, you can just use `nn.NLLLoss()`.

[Here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html) is an example from PyTorchs documentation

```
m = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)
loss = nn.NLLLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=True)
target = torch.tensor([1, 0, 4])
output = loss(m(input), target)
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I am kind of looking for the same approach but using `nn.Softmax` instead of `nn.LogSoftmax`. I want the output to be bound to [0,1], but LogSoftmax unfortunately isn't.